# how to style custom controls to appear next to native html5 video controls

Tags: javascript, html5-video

[image: Image representing question 1]I have a basic html5 video tag with the native controls. I have added 3 custom control buttons, 1 for next video, previous video and a replay video control button.

Question 1.How can I style the custom controls to appear in-line with or next to the native controls?The image attached depicts what I would like to achieve.

Question 2.I know how to get the replay button to display when the video ends (using JavaScript),but how can I make that happen on the video itself,rather than on the controls bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should place video and controls in one container.
Disable default controls of the video.
Build your custom controls with HTML and place above video using z-index.
Bind controls click events and change video state with JS.
F.E.

```
<div id="video-container">
  <video id="video" controls="false">
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
    <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```